# Do there exist two spaces such that there is no continuous, non-constant function between them?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Do there exist two topological spaces $(X,\tau_X)$ and $(Y,\tau_Y)$, each with more than one point, so that no continuous non-constant function $f:X\to Y$ exists?

**Edit:** As Krish commented, an example of this would be to take $X$ connected and $Y$ discrete with more than one point, so now I propose the question:

Do there exist two topological spaces $(X,\tau_X)$ and $(Y,\tau_Y)$, each with more than one point, so that no continuous non-constant function $f:X\to Y$ or $f:Y\to X$ exists?

**Edit 2:** I added the assumption that $X$ and $Y$ have at least two points.

Comment: Take $X$ connected, and $Y$ discrete space with more than one points.

Comment: @Krish Of course! Thank you, I made a change on the question to make it a little harder, I think.

Comment: Take one of $X$ or $Y$ to be empty, or a single point.

Comment: @MartianInvader Any function with empty domain is continuous.

Comment: @SergioEnriqueYarzaAcuña: Any function with empty domain is also constant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a neat example.  Take $X=[0,1]$ with the usual topology and let $Y$ be a countably infinite set with the cofinite topology.  Then any continuous map $Y\to X$ is constant, since $X$ is Hausdorff but there are no disjoint nonempty open sets in $Y$.  On the other hand, there are no nonconstant continuous maps $X\to Y$ either (this is tricky to prove; for instance, see [this question on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48970/why-are-the-integers-with-the-cofinite-topology-not-path-connected)).

Answer (score 3):

Examples similar to Eric's exist even if you insist on Hausdorff spaces. Take $X=[0,1]$ (with the standard topology) and $Y$ which is countably infinite, Hausdorff and connected (e.g. the irrational slope topology). Then every continuous map $X\to Y$ and $Y\to X$ is constant.